Nuxt "/_loading/sse" results in "ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK)"
Issue
In order to overcome CORS and TLS/SSL issues during Nuxt 2.14 project development, a Docker Nginx and Node containers are in use, where Nginx is also used as a reverse-proxy.
DevTools Console is currently indicating these regular request failures:
GET https://test.testpay.local:444/_loading/sse net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 (OK) :444/_loading/sse:1



Nginx Proxy Container logs indicated the following issue:
test-dp-webserver  | 2024/05/24 12:45:07 [error] 235#235: *309 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: test.testpay.local, request: "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.22.0.3:3000/_loading/sse", host: "test.testpay.local:444", referrer: "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment"
test-dp-webserver  | 172.22.0.1 - - [24/May/2024:12:45:07 +0000] "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
test-dp-webserver  | 2024/05/24 12:46:10 [error] 238#238: *319 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: test.testpay.local, request: "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.22.0.3:3000/_loading/sse", host: "test.testpay.local:444", referrer: "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment"
test-dp-webserver  | 172.22.0.1 - - [24/May/2024:12:46:10 +0000] "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
test-dp-webserver  | 2024/05/24 12:47:13 [error] 235#235: *349 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: test.testpay.local, request: "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.22.0.3:3000/_loading/sse", host: "test.testpay.local:444", referrer: "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment"
test-dp-webserver  | 172.22.0.1 - - [24/May/2024:12:47:13 +0000] "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
test-dp-webserver  | 2024/05/24 12:48:17 [error] 235#235: *351 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading upstream, client: 172.22.0.1, server: test.testpay.local, request: "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.22.0.3:3000/_loading/sse", host: "test.testpay.local:444", referrer: "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment"
test-dp-webserver  | 172.22.0.1 - - [24/May/2024:12:48:17 +0000] "GET /_loading/sse HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "https://test.testpay.local:444/@5/payment" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"

Environment
Nginx Container Configuration
upstream nuxt {
    ip_hash;

    server test-node:3000;
}

server {
  server_name 'test.testpay.local';

  listen 443 ssl;

  include '/etc/nginx/mime.types';

  # SSL
  # --------------------------------

  include './conf.d/tls/main.conf';
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

  # Proxy
  # --------------------------------

  proxy_next_upstream error;

  # Locations
  # ----------------------------------------------------------------

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host               '$host';
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          '$remote_addr';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    '$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for';
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  '$scheme';

    proxy_pass http://nuxt;
  }
}

Docker Compose Excerpt
services:
# ...

  webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: test-webserver
    hostname: test-webserver

    environment:
      MAIN_HOST: "$NGINX_DOMAIN"
      NUXT_HOST: 'test-node'
      NUXT_PORT: "$NUXT_PORT"
      API_HOST: "$API_HOST"

    volumes:
      - './.project/docker/nginx/templates/:/etc/nginx/templates/:ro'
      - './.project/security/tls:/etc/tls:ro'

    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:81:80'
      - '127.0.0.1:444:443'

    networks:
      - test-frontend

    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'

    depends_on:
      node:
        condition: service_started

  node:
    image: node:18
    working_dir: '/var/www/'
    container_name: test-node
    hostname: test-node
    mem_limit: 4096m
    mem_reservation: 4096m
    cpus: 2

    volumes:
      - './:/var/www/'

    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:9229:9229'

    networks:
      - test-frontend

# ...

Question
What might it be? Is it expected or how would you debug the connection/cause deeper?

After some investigation, it appears to be a misconfiguration between proxy and Nuxt SSE (i.e. Loading Screen Module for Nuxt.js).

Evidently, this "loading-screen" is active on the background with the project already built and running.
Content-Type: text/event-stream header received from the Nuxt module required a continuous connection for Server-Sent Events or SSE to work, and proxy was terminating connection too soon where no message was sent from the Nuxt end.
An increase of the default 60s (as of 2024-05) Nginx setting proxy read timeout to something longer like 3600s solved the issue. In this case, we expect the Nuxt end to send anything within that limit to the client.
In other words, the following changes should be done in the above Nginx reverse-proxy configuration:
location / {
  proxy_set_header Host               '$host';
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          '$remote_addr';
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    '$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for';
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  '$scheme';

  proxy_read_timeout 3600;

  proxy_pass http://nuxt;
}

Et voila!

However, it's worth to mention:

Nginx setting proxy_buffering off; may be required, too, since it was recommended in this answer, yet I had no issues without it set.




The Chrome browser will kill an inactive stream after two minutes of inactivity. If
you want to keep it alive, you need to add some code to send something from the server to the browser at least once every two minutes.
Source

Related

Server-Sent Events connection timeout on Node.js via Nginx...
Why do I get many SSE request that slow down my webpage in my NUXT.js project?...
Getting net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING 200 when consuming event-stream...
Chrome net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING error...

